# SSH resource unavailable when connecting

Tags: ssh

I have created a Virtual Machine with `multipass`, I am trying to connect to this instance over `ssh`, with the command:

> ssh -vvv -i back_key ubuntu@10.136.38.199

At first, I tried to connect to my instance from a `Github Action`, but I got a timeout error, I thought that it may have been a Github issue.
But with a second computer, I couldn't connect to the VM either.

- The error I got:

```
ubuntu@laptop-number2:~$ ssh -vvv -i back_key ubuntu@10.136.38.199
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.136.38.199 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.136.38.199 [10.136.38.199] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.136.38.199 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
ssh: connect to host 10.136.38.199 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Wheither it's from `Github Action` or from a second computer, I can't connect to the `multipass` instance over ssh.

**But**, I can connect to instance with the host computer. 
I thought it may be a Firewall issue, so I disabled it with:

> sudo systemctl stop ufw

I did this in the VM and the host machine, then I restarted `ssh` inside the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason: I got those issues was the network I was working on. The ssh port for the server couldn't be reached.
I knew that by using nmap:

> nmap -Pn -p 22 <IP_OF_SERVER>

The result was: The port is filtered.
Working with a mobile network didn't solve it either, since my ISP block this port. The solution was using the network from my house for the ssh server.